# Laravel leftJoin not return correctly

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a problem with laravel select using leftJoin. I'm trying to select 2 posts and count how many comments there is(first post have 7 comments, second - 0), but I got only first post with 7 comments.

Code is:

```
$posts = DB::table('posts')
        ->leftJoin('comments', 'comments.post', '=', 'posts.id')
        ->select(DB::raw('posts.title, posts.body, posts.created_at, posts.slug, CASE WHEN comments.post IS NULL THEN 0 WHEN comments.post IS NOT NULL THEN count(comments.post) END as count'))
        ->get();
```

And when I trying to check what i see in web browser i got error:
`Call to a member function count() on a non-object`

This error in my view file at line where i using `@if($posts->count())`

I have debugged that i got only one post from using `print_r()`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best bet here is to use some of the built in functionality of laravel's Eloquent ORM.

set up a relationship in the models:

**Post.php:**

```
<?php

class Post extends Eloquent {

   protected $table = 'posts';

   public function comments()
   {
      return $this->hasMany('Comment', 'posts');//first param refrences the other model, second is the foreign key
   }
```

**Comment.php:**

```
<?php

class Comment extends Eloquent {

   protected $table = 'comments';

   public function comments()
   {
      return $this->belongsTo('Post');//first param refrences the other model, second is unnecessary if you are using auto incrementing id
   }
```

now you have a relationship set up and there is no need for the join.

**Usage:**

there may be a better way to do this, but this should work.

```
  $posts = Post::with('comments')->get();//retrieves all posts with comments
   foreach($posts as $post){
     $count = count($post['comments']);
     $post['comment_count'] = $count;
  }
  return $posts;
```

this will return a result that contains all of the posts, with a field called 'comments' that contains an array of all of the comments related. the 'comment_count' field will contain the count.

**example:**

```
[
  {
   "id": 1,
    "created_at": "2014-07-02 11:34:00",
    "updated_at": "2014-07-02 11:34:00",
    "post_title": "hello there",
    "comment_count": 1,
    "comments": [
        {
          "id":'blah'
          "comment_title":"blah"
        }
     ]
```

}

you can now pass this to your view and loop through each post and get the `$post['comment_count']`

Comment: Hey, can I add one more model to relationship?

Comment: not sure what you mean, but you can relate any of your models. simply add another function referencing the other other just like I did above with the `comments` function

Comment: One more question! How can I add comments now? Old version not works.

Comment: can you post your code, either create  a new question or update your post

Comment: i found what the problem, now i need to use `$addComment->save()` before i have used only `$addComment`